# Android studio version 4.01 update

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Just updated the Android studio, need to update an old app put together using version 3.0. I am getting error message when trying to load program into the IDE.

> The specified Gradle distribution
> 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip' does
> not appear to contain a Gradle distribution.

What is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Download **gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip** via [this link](https://gradle.org/next-steps/?version=5.1.1&format=bin)
2. copy **gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip** to the gradle/wrapper directory
   [image]
3. Open **gradle-wrapper.properties** , change the last line as:

> distributionUrl=gradle-5.1.1-bin.zip

4. sync project with gradle again.

Comment: distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

update your code in  `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

and in file `build.gradle(project level)`

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
```